# Adding parameters to custom List button with intermediate record type selection screen

Tags: record-type, list-button

We have a Quote object with Price as the child object. When creating a Price record from parent's related list, we are currently redirected to the standard record type screen. Can we somehow override the related list new and edit buttons with custom parameters passed to the URL (URL type List button) and still get those parameters after the record type selection screen to be used on our custom page/component.

Comment: Are you in lightning or classic?

Comment: @Pranay We are in Lightning right now.